# Blazor API - Display (pdf,xlsx,ppt,video) in new tab instead of download prompt

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

API-Server Side

public FileResult DownloadFile(int ProductID, string FileName , int UserID)

```
{
var folderName = Path.Combine("Files", root);
string FilePath = '';
FilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);
var fullPath = Path.Combine(FilePath, FileName);
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + FileName);
 return File(fileBytes,System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet,FileName);
}
```

The result is always downloaded file without display.

Do I have to add something special to the response to get the browser to open the files automatically?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends from your client browser settings.

If you want to "try" to open the file without downloading it, the browser of the user should be capable to understand the file format.

In case of PDF you need to specify `"Content-type: application/pdf"` instead of `Octet` as you use in the source code.

The mime types have a helper class with these values:

```
namespace System.Net.Mime
{
    public static class MediaTypeNames
    {
        public static class Text
        {
            public const string Plain = "text/plain";
            public const string Html = "text/html";
            public const string Xml = "text/xml";
            public const string RichText = "text/richtext";
        }

        public static class Application
        {
            public const string Soap = "application/soap+xml";
            public const string Octet = "application/octet-stream";
            public const string Rtf = "application/rtf";
            public const string Pdf = "application/pdf";
            public const string Zip = "application/zip";
            public const string Json = "application/json";
            public const string Xml = "application/xml";
        }

        public static class Image
        {
            public const string Gif = "image/gif";
            public const string Tiff = "image/tiff";
            public const string Jpeg = "image/jpeg";
        }
    }
}
```

So in your case you can use `System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf`.

But, as I wrote, it depends on the computer software installed and integrated in the browser.